# ImageView is not adjusting according to screen size

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, android-imageview

My filter image in toolbar is going out of screen for small width phones but it's working properly for pixel2 like phones.

Screenshot

[image]

xml code

```
       <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/filter1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView7"
            android:layout_marginStart="310dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"/>
```

It is in Relativelayout.

Please solve my problem.

Comment: Don't use dp sizes

Comment: Make your layout with constraint layout

Comment: Use `android:layout_alignParentTop:true` and `android:layout_alignParentRight:true` instead of your `android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView7"`

Comment: But I want fix size for all screen size

Answer (score 0):

put your image in `RelativeLayout` and use  `align_parent`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <ImageView
          android:layout_width="30dp"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:src="@drawable/filter1"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```